# How to show that the transition probabilities are continuous.

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a continuous time Markov chain $X_t$. It satisfies these four assumptions:

> 1. It has a finite number, $N$ of states.
> 2. For arbitrary $j,k,s$ and $t$ with $s<t$, assume that $X_s=j$ and consider the probability $X_t=k$. This probability does not change if
>      information about the behaviour of the process during the interval
>      $[0,s)$ is added to the knowledge that $X_s=j$.
> 3. $\lim\limits_{t \downarrow s}P_{jk}(s,t)=\delta_{jk}$ for all $j,k, s \ge 0$where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta.
> 4. For all $j,k, j\ne k$ and all $t \ge 0$:
>
> $\mu_{jk}(t)=\lim\limits_{\Delta t \downarrow
>  0}\frac{P_{jk}(t,t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}$,
>
> exits and is continuous in $t$.

Then the author says:

> By these for assumptions, it may be shown that for each $s\ge 0$ each
>   $P_{jk}(s,\cdot)$ is continuous for all $t\ge s$.

But how is this shown? I am able to show right-continuity, but not left-continuity. I show right-continuity like this:

$P_{jk}(s,t+\Delta t)=\sum\limits_{\nu} P_{j\nu}(s,t)P_{\nu k}(t,t+\Delta t)$. By taking the limits on both sides and using assumption $3$ the result follows.

But to show left-continuity I start like this:

$P_{jk}(s,t)=\sum\limits_{\nu} P_{j\nu}(s,t-\Delta t)P_{\nu k}(t-\Delta t,t)$.

And here I get stuck, because what can we say about the limits $\lim\limits_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}P_{\nu k}(t-\Delta t,t)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use the continuity of $\mu_{jk}$ here to show $\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} P_{jk}(t - \Delta t,t) = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} P_{jk}(t,t+ \Delta t)$.  We have

\begin{align*}
&\left| \frac{P_{jk}(t - \Delta t,t) - P_{jk}(t,t+ \Delta t)}{\Delta t} \right| = \left| \frac{P_{jk}(t - \Delta t,t)}{\Delta t} - \mu_{jk}(t - \Delta t) + \mu_{jk}(t - \Delta t)  - \mu_{jk}(t + \Delta t) + \mu_{jk}(t+\Delta t)  - \frac{ P_{jk}(t,t+ \Delta t)}{\Delta t} \right| \\
&\le  \left| \frac{P_{jk}(t - \Delta t,t)}{\Delta t} - \mu_{jk}(t - \Delta t)\right| + \left|\mu_{jk}(t - \Delta t)  - \mu_{jk}(t )\right| + \left|\mu_{jk}(t)  - \frac{ P_{jk}(t,t+ \Delta t)}{\Delta t} \right|
\end{align*}

and taking the limit in the first and third term gives $0$ from the definition of $\mu_{jk}$, and $0$ in the middle term from the continuity of $\mu_{jk}$.

Comment: But we don't know that the first term in the last sum goes to zero? The definition only says that the last term goes to zero?